# JMagick automation using Eclipse(JAVA)

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, imagemagick, jmagick

I am trying to develop automation program to capture two images and then compare those images to see if they are similar or not.

I am using Windows 7 and Eclipse IDE (JAVA) with Selenium web-driver.

I have done my research and found JMagick would be the best fit for me but i have been unsuccessful making it work with eclipse. I have installed JMagick, ImageMagick and have added the local libraries to the eclipse.

The problem is that i can not find any guides or helpful links that can help me understand the following problems. How do i automate JMagick to take screenshot? How do i save those taken screenshots? And how do i compare those taken screenshots pixel by pixel? All of these using JMagick and at the end how do i display the diff image?

If anyone has any ideas or know of any guides please provide them! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: anyone? I need to get this done soon..

Comment: can't post my code as it's kinda long and not allowing me to post..

Comment: Is it possible to just run the ImageMagick command from the java? Like how would i go about it if i wanted to run, "compare img1.png img2.png -compose src diff.png"  Any help?

Comment: were you able to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) instead? JMagick is not enough documented. You have to look at the ImageMagick documentation.

However, if I were you, I would write a script to be called from your code.

To take a screenshot:

```
import -window root screen.jpeg
```

Also, to compare two images, you can read this [guide](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php)

I hope this help you!

Comment: Thanks for this! But i was looking for more code specific answers. If you can provide that as well it will be great! So far this is what i kinda have.