# How to use imagemagick to compare two images and get the difference with java code?

Tags: java, imagemagick

I could use Imagemagick to compare two images and get the difference image through command line using - 'compare image1.png image2.png output.png'. But I am not sure what code to write or what to install so that imagemagick works in **java code** to compare images.

Comment: Use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Comment: Here is answer for image comparision in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760602/jmagick-image-comparision